# Neo4jHelper is missing in spring-data-neo4j 3.3.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-neo4j

I've upgraded my spring-data-neo4j from 3.2.3 to 3.3.0 and found that the Neo4jHelper class is missing. The class itself is not marked as deprecated.

Comment: I have the same issue. What should be used instead of Neo4jHelper ?

Comment: It was moved to test resources. Just add spring-data-neo4j maven dependency with "test" classifier.

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
   <version>3.3.0.RELEASE</version>
   <classifier>test</classifier>
  </dependency>
Error: Missing artifact org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:jar:test:3.3.0.RELEASE

Comment: How to correctly add it ?

Comment: I got it ! This is "tests" not "test". Thank you very much !